# links to scoped routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'd like to use scoped routes for internationalizing. Here's my routes.rb

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pl/ do

  resources :announcements, only: [:index], path: '/news'
  resources :diplomas, only: [:index, :show], path: '/graduates'

end
```

**Goal** is to point urls like website.domain/pl/news to announcements controller and then check params[:locale] in ApplicationController in some `before_action` method.

But I have **problems** with generating urls. As I said before I want only good looking urls and my sense of aesthetics tells me that appname.domain/news/?locales=pl is not something I'm looking for. :(

So I have question:
Is there any option to generate links like appname.domain/pl/news/ when using scoped routes?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are scoped in a way, so that they can be called like this:

```
your.domain/pl/news
your.domain/en/news
```

if this pleases your aesthetics.

So, in other word, yes.

Have a look here, on how to use and set this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale

Comment: Yes, that's true, when I go to my.domain/pl/news everything seems to work, but I don't know how to call link_to helper that generates link these links.

Comment: Since this is rather a user specific setting, I'd suggest to save it in the session. With setting the `locale` your routes should be created accordingly.

Comment: I've included the section, where it is explained, how you can set the locale.

Comment: Ok. Now it works. The problem was caused by the placement of scoped routes (bottom of file) so it was override by other rules - I guess I didn't understand scoped routes well, now everything seems to be clear (and links are beautiful!), thanks!